# Problem with Castle configuration in TFS2010 build machine?

Tags: testing, c#-4.0, build, castle

I have a system that implements several web services in C# 4.0. The solution is being compiled under TFS2010's build mechanism.  After the build, some low level tests are run.

These run correctly in developer studio (on Windows 7), but for some reason fail under MSTest on the build machine (Windows Server 2008 R2).  Some logging shows that it's caused by a System.IO.FileNotFoundException exception on an assembly at the bottom layer (see exception stack below).

Do you think it's a versioning problem? Is Windows Server 2008 R2 doing something completely different that the Castle asembly doesn't grok?

> Type: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
>   Error Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>   Source: mscorlib
>
> Type: Castle.MicroKernel.SubSystems.Conversion.ConverterException
>   Error Message: Could not convert from 'MockRepository' to System.Type.
>   Source: Castle.Windsor
>
> Type: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
>    Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'VsWebSite.Interop, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>    Source: mscorlib

**EDIT:** I never did find out what the problem was.  I had a large amount of refactoring to do and, after that was over, the issue disappeared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something is referencing VsWebSite.Interop.dll (definitely not any Castle assembly) which is a Visual Studio assembly, and you probably don't have Visual Studio installed on your build server. Remove that reference.

Comment: Thanks for the comment!  I've just run through all the projects in the solution file, and none of them explicitly call on VsWebSite.Interop.dll.  Nor does running the Dependency Walker show that DLL up in any of the generated assemblies.  Do you think it be something to do with the way the app.config / web.config is configired?

Comment: @Peter K: definitely, I've seen that Visual Studio may automatically add that to your app.config/web.config. If so, remove it.